# Merging datasets based on more than 1 column in both datasets

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to merge two datasets, by year and country. The first data set (df = GNIPC) represent Gross national income per capite for every country from 1980-2008.

```
         Country  Year GNIpc
       (chr) (dbl) (dbl)
1    Afghanistan  1990    NA
2    Afghanistan  1991    NA
3    Afghanistan  1992  2010
4    Afghanistan  1993    NA
5    Afghanistan  1994 12550
6    Afghanistan  1995    NA
```

The second dataset (df = sanctions) represents the imposition of economic sanctions from 1946 to present day.

```
      country imposition sanctiontype sanctions_period
      (chr)      (dbl)        (chr)            (chr)
1 Afghanistan       1     1 6 8           1997-2001
2 Afghanistan       1     7               1979-1979
3 Afghanistan       1     4 7             1995-2002
4 Albania           1     2 8             2005-2005
5 Albania           1     7               2005-2006
6 Albania           1     8               2004-2005
```

I would like to merge the two datasets so that for every GNI year i either have sanctions present in the country or not. For the GNI years that are not in the sanctions_period the value would be 0 and for those that are it would be 1. This is what i want it to look like:

```
         Country  Year GNIpc Imposition sanctiontype
           (chr) (dbl) (dbl)   (dbl)        (chr)
1    Afghanistan  1990    NA    0            NA
2    Afghanistan  1991    NA    0            NA
3    Afghanistan  1992  2010    0            NA
4    Afghanistan  1993    NA    0            NA
5    Afghanistan  1994 12550    0            NA
6    Afghanistan  1995    NA    1           4 7
```

Comment: I wouldn't work with the second dataset in that format. If someone handed me that data I would (1) cringe, (2) get to work converting it so that there is a single row for each combination of `sanctiontype` and each year in `sanctions_period`. So `Afganistan` would have five rows with `sanctiontype = 1`, one for each of the years 1997-2001.

Comment: what should it look like for Afganistan 1998? Would it be one row for each sanction period (2), or one row with `1 4 6 7 8`?

Comment: I have done a different dataset in which  each sanctionstype has its own row.. Here I'm looking for a way to determine for each GNI year whether there is a sanction in place that year or not. Looking past the type of sanctions how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(country = c('Afghanistan', 'Turkey'), 
                  imposition = c(1, 0), 
                  sanctiontype = c('1 6 8', '4'), 
                  sanctions_period = c('1997-2001', '2003-ongoing')
)

      country imposition sanctiontype sanctions_period
1 Afghanistan          1        1 6 8        1997-2001
2      Turkey          0            4     2012-ongoing
```

The "sanctions_period" column can be transformed with *dplyr* and *tidyr*:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df.new <- separate(df1, sanctions_period, c('start', 'end'), remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(end = ifelse(end == 'ongoing', '2016', end)) %>% 
  mutate(start = as.numeric(start), end = as.numeric(end)) %>% 
  group_by(country, sanctions_period) %>% 
  do(data.frame(country = .$country, imposition = .$imposition, sanctiontype = .$sanctiontype, year = .$start:.$end))

   sanctions_period     country imposition sanctiontype  year
             <fctr>      <fctr>      <dbl>       <fctr> <int>
1         1997-2001 Afghanistan          1        1 6 8  1997
2         1997-2001 Afghanistan          1        1 6 8  1998
3         1997-2001 Afghanistan          1        1 6 8  1999
4         1997-2001 Afghanistan          1        1 6 8  2000
5         1997-2001 Afghanistan          1        1 6 8  2001
6      2012-ongoing      Turkey          0            4  2012
7      2012-ongoing      Turkey          0            4  2013
8      2012-ongoing      Turkey          0            4  2014
9      2012-ongoing      Turkey          0            4  2015
10     2012-ongoing      Turkey          0            4  2016
```

From there, it should easy to merge with your first data frame. Note that your first data frame capitalizes Country and Year, while the second doesn't.

```
df.merged <- merge(df.first, df.new, by.x = c('Country', 'Year'), by.y = c('country', 'year'))
```

Comment: I did the following on my dataset, but got an error:
  `df.new <- separate(sanctions4, sanctions_period, c('start', 'end'), remove = F) %>% 
      mutate(start = as.numeric(start), end = as.numeric(end)) %>% 
      group_by(country, sanctions_period) %>% 
      do(data.frame(country = .$country, imposition = .$imposition, sanctiontype = .$sanctiontype, year = .$start:.$end))`



    `Error in .$start:.$end : NA/NaN argument`

Comment: Could it be because for some observations the 'sanction_period' is for example 1990-ongoing, therefore when i separate the column and tranform end(year) to numeric i get NA's for the observations that have an end year of ongoing. Therefore there is no end year for some observations and R needs there to be in order to run the following command?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I've modified example data and solution to account for rows in which the ending sanctions_period year is "ongoing".

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as the solution when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
left_join(GNIPC, sanctions, by=c("Country"="country", "Year"="Year")) %>%
  select(Country,Year, GNIpc, Imposition, sanctiontype)
```

Comment: Thanks. However in the second dataframe i don't have a year variable and instead a range sanctions_period

Comment: As `joran` pointed out in a comment, you'd need to tidy up your data. that is:

    Afghanistan       1     1 6 8           1997-2001

Comment: Sorry: As `joran` pointed out in a comment, you'd need to tidy up your data. that is:

`Afghanistan       1     1 6 8           1997-2001` needs to become 15 rows, one for each `sanctiontype` and `year` in the range.